# Scriptable utility to convert BMPs + WAV to video (XviD)?

Tags: scripting, ffmpeg, wav, video-encoding, bmp

I'm looking for a scriptable utility to convert a bunch of BMPs and a WAV file into a video.  XviD needs to be the output format.  I'd like it to work on Linux (Ubuntu) if possible.  A command line utility would be great, as I have 36 videos to create this way.  A `bash` (or [insert favorite scripting language here]) script would be great for this.  (I also need to play around with different video dimensions, but I can use other programs to resize.)

I've played around with VirtualDub (for Windows XP), but it doesn't seem to meet these needs.  I could be wrong, though.  Any pointers to examples would be great.

I'm also playing with `ffmpeg`.  It seems to fit the bill perfectly, but I can't seem to get it to pull together the BMPs into a video.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
for directory in $BMP_DIRECTORY_PATH/*
do
    ffmpeg \
        -f image2 \
        -i "$directory/Sequence %d%d%d%d%d%d.bmp" \
        -r 29.97 \
        -vcodec mpeg4 \
        -vtag xvid \
        \
        -i "$file/audio.wav" \
        -acodec libmp3lame \
        \
        $(basename $directory.avi)
done
```

And here's what it's saying back:

```
[...]

FFmpeg version 0.5-svn17737+3:0.svn20090303-1ubuntu6, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --extra-version=svn17737+3:0.svn20090303-1ubuntu6 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-libdc1394 --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 --disable-armvfp --disable-neon --disable-altivec --disable-vis --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Apr 10 2009 23:18:41, gcc: 4.3.3
[image2 @ 0x97e5ac0]Could not find codec parameters (Video: bmp)
/home/ben/Pending/1080p_export/6/Sequence %d%d%d%d%d%d.bmp: could not find codec parameters
```

I've seen a [mailing list post](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2007-March/007736.html) about this, but what is suggested doesn't seem to work here.

**UPDATE**

Here's the updated script with multiple steps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# bmp+wav2xvid+mp3
# 
# Although it has a cryptic name, it's pretty descriptive.  This script consumes BMPs (Windows bitmaps) and WAVs (Microsoft AD-PCM Waveforms) to make an XviD (MPEG-4 video) movie.
# 
# By convention, you pass it a directory with one or more directories that contain:
#
#     * Frames named "frame_001.bmp", "frame_002.bmp", etc.
#     * Audio named "audio.wav"
# 
# Author: Benjamin Oakes

# FIXME: The audio doesn't get muxed correctly.  The A/V sync is off a little.  At the beginning it looks pretty okay, but by the end the mouths definitely don't match up with the words that are said.

#############################################################
# NOTE: SEE `ffmpeg -formats` for a list of available formats
#############################################################

# BMP_DIRECTORY_PATH="/home/ben/Outbox/ffmpeg.fixture/"
BMP_DIRECTORY_PATH="/media/Archival Data/Video Projects Backup/Video Projects/1080p_export_dual_gray/"

# Output settings
VTAG="xvid"
VCODEC="mpeg4"
ACODEC="libmp3lame"
DIMENSIONS="1000x562"
FPS="35"
CONTAINER="avi"

if [ -d "$BMP_DIRECTORY_PATH" ]; then
  echo "BMP directory exists"

  # for directory in "$BMP_DIRECTORY_PATH"/*
  # do
    directory="/media/Archival Data/Video Projects Backup/Video Projects/1080p_export_dual_gray/1"

    ffmpeg \
      -f image2 \
      -i "$directory/frame_%03d.bmp" \
      -vcodec mpeg1video \
      -sameq \
      \
      -r $FPS \
      "../tmp/$(basename "$directory.mpg")"

    ffmpeg \
      -i "../tmp/$(basename "$directory.mpg")" \
      -vcodec $VCODEC \
      -vtag $VTAG \
      -s $DIMENSIONS \
      -sameq \
      \
      -i "$directory/audio.wav" \
      -acodec $ACODEC \
      -ar 8000 \
      \
      -f $CONTAINER \
      -r $FPS \
      "../tmp/$(basename "$directory")-$VTAG-$VCODEC-$ACODEC-$DIMENSIONS-$FPS.$CONTAINER"
  # done
else
  echo "ERROR: BMP directory does not exist"
fi
```

**UPDATE 2**

Please see my answer for what I ended up getting to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with, just for other people's reference.

```
# bmp+wav2xvid+mp3
# 
# Although it has a cryptic name, it's pretty descriptive.  This script consumes BMPs and WAVs to make an XviD (MPEG-4 video) movie.
# 
# By convention, you pass it a directory with one or more directories that contain:
#
#     * Frames named "frame_001.bmp", "frame_002.bmp", etc.
#     * Audio named "audio.wav"
# 
# Author: Benjamin Oakes

# Output settings
VTAG="xvid"
VCODEC="mpeg4"
ACODEC="libmp3lame"
ABITRATE="128k"
QSCALE="1"
DIMENSIONS="1000x562"
FPS="24000/1001"
CONTAINER="avi"

if [ -d "$BMP_DIRECTORY_PATH" ]; then
  echo "BMP directory exists"

  for directory in "$BMP_DIRECTORY_PATH"
  do
    ffmpeg \
      -f image2 \
      -r 24000/1001 \
      -i "$directory/frame_%03d.bmp" \
      \
      \
      -i "$directory/audio.wav" \
      \
      \
      -vcodec $VCODEC \
      -vtag $VTAG \
      -qscale $QSCALE \
      -s $DIMENSIONS \
      -r $FPS \
      \
      -acodec $ACODEC \
      -ab $ABITRATE \
      \
      "../tmp/$(basename "$directory").avi"
  done
else
  echo "ERROR: BMP directory does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do too much at once.  Try breaking the task up into three discrete actions:

- create video from bmp images
- mux in the audio
- encode to target format

To that end, I would suggest using mpeg1 as your intermediate video format.

Comment: This helped a lot -- I'm posting the updated script I have above.  I'm having problems muxing the audio, though.  (The A/V sync is off.)

Comment: Any ideas on what's causing the A/V synchrony problem?  I'm considering making a new question about that.

Comment: How much are they off?  Under 1s, but still painful?  Does it become more of a problem the more clips you add?  How many clips are you doing?  Yea, probably best for a new question.  But I'd start by analyzing the length of the individual components before concatenating and remuxing.  You should be able to trim/pad the audio to make it an exact match.  There are probably other techniques too.  Yea...another question...

Comment: And if you are adjusting the audio rate on the fly then you might run into issues.  Try leaving the native audio rate.  (Same for video.)  Adjusting either rate smells like it could result in synch errors...gotta love rounding...